# Arduino: How to get Data from RX pin

Tags: arduino, serial-port, rxtx

I am trying to connect a U-blox C94-M8P development board to a [LinkIt One](https://labs.mediatek.com/site/global/developer_tools/mediatek_linkit/documentation/overview/index.gsp) via serial connection. I found several ways to do so, but none of them seems to work. Though I have to say, that I once managed to attach the two boards together and it worked, meaning the M8P sent GPS Data to my LinkIt...But because the antenna did not work while the board was attached, I disconnected it again and forgot how I did it...

For now, I connect RX, TX, GND and 3.3V to [J4 Connector](https://www.u-blox.com/de/files/c94-m8p-application-board-user-guide) (page 21) and the LEDs on the LinkIt for TX and RX are glowing, so I assume there should be a connection and the possibility to receive data. Though when I try to make a Serial1 connection, it always fails.
This is my LinkIt code, with many variations of possible ways to output the signals...none of them works:

```
#include <UARTClass.h>
#include <string.h>


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial begins");

  Serial1.begin(9600);
  //Serial1.end();
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(0,INPUT);

  Serial.write(analogRead(0));

  if(Serial1.available()>0){
    Serial.println(Serial1.available());
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    Serial1.write("Hello World");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("No Serial1 available");
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial1.available()>0){
    Serial1.begin(9600);    
    //Serial.write(Serial1.read());
    String msg=Serial1.readString();
    //char* token=strtok(msg, '$');
    //Serial.println(msg);
    Serial.println(analogRead(0));
    delay(5000);
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("No Serial1 available");
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //for(int i = 0; i<7;i++){
    //Serial.print(analogRead(0));
    //}
    Serial.println(analogRead(0));
   // delay(5000);
  }
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
832
No Serial1 available
```

For now the programm goes into the last `else`. I also tried to connect the LinkIt using J8 connector on the C94 with pin 4 for GND, pin 9 for RX (connected to TX on the LinkIt) and pin 10 for TX. With that setup, only the RX light is glowing, the TX light isn't. Another setup I tried is like the one before, but with pin 7 as TX and pin 8 as RX, but with the same outcome.

Has anyone an idea on how to solve this problem? *I thought maybe when the lights are glowing it is possible to get the data without a serial connection?* I really don't get what the board is doing, as well as what I have to change to make it work or what I did differently the last time. As the C94 is quite complex with all kinds of messages that can be sent or not it is very possible, that I need to change something in the configuration of the C94.

If someone knows something to help me solve this problem I am happy to hear. I know of the U-blox forum, but I hope to reach more people here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check UBX-CFG-MSG settings?

UBX, RTCM3 or NMEA should be turned on appropriately for the purposes.